# Access elements which are loaded via jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm pretty new to jQuery and this issue has me stumped for a good couple of hours now.

**Assuming I have a html structure like so (excerpt):**

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" class="write" id="write01"/>
    <div id="subDiv2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="text" class="write" id="write02"/>
    <div id="subDiv2"></div>
</div>
```

**And an attached JavaScript file like so (excerpt):**

```
$(function(){

    var $my_focus = null;

    var $my_container = null;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".write").focus(function(){

            if ($my_container !== null){
                $my_container.empty();
            }

            $my_focus = $(':focus');

            $my_container = $my_focus.next("div");

            $my_container.load("some.jsp");

        });

    });

});
```

**And lets assume the JSP file contains a html table structure which will act as buttons:**

```
<div class="someContainer" id="someId">

    <table class="someTableClass" id="someTableId" >

        <tr class="someRowClass">

              <td class="commonClass specialClass1">Button1</td>

              <td class="commonClass specialClass2">Button2</td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

All is well and good with this so far, the JSP file loads successfully into the sibling div of the input field in which the user clicks into, however...

**The question is:**

How can I set up a listener that will trigger when for example I click on one of the `td` elements which are loaded in?

Naively I tried to do it similarly with the `$(document).ready` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.commonClass').click(function(){

        alert("hello);

    });

});
```

But that obviously only works if I had the JSP loaded in from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `td` elements are dynamically loaded, you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.commonClass', function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Also, you can tidy up your original code, as there is no need to re-select the element which has `:focus`:

```
$(".write").focus(function() {
    $(this).next("div").empty().load("some.jsp");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, although if I tidy it up like you described, the loaded JSPs don't remove themselves when I focus the next input field (although I didn't mention this in the original post, it's what I was trying to achieve with that) But regardless I could discard `$my_focus` as you said and replace that with `$(this)`, so again thanks for the insight. :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation to attach event handler on dynamically added elements

```
$(document.body).on('click','.commonClass',function(){
```